# Read Value from URL in PHP

Tags: php

I have a link on Home Page say for eg

```
<a href="count.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>&desc=<?php echo $row['PRO']; ?>" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">**Home**</a></li>
```

Once click on Home Link provided above it goes to next page that is

`http://abb/MyWeb/pr/arro/count.php?id=4&desc=It%20isavailable`

Now I want to read value from URL

`id=4` and 
`desc=it is available`

and I want to store it in variable

`$idenity = id1` ( store the id from url to variable )

Comment: I don't wish to offend but this is so vastly beginner stuff that you need to finish reading about PHP and learning the basics before coming here with these questions. This is like, instead of clicking 'install', going to a forum and asking how to install a program you just got. That's how basic this is.

Comment: A side comment: the `&` character should be represented as `&amp;` in HTML (view, for example, the source HTML of this page). Some browsers tolerate `&` in the href attribute of an anchor because it is a common error but it’s better to stick to standards where you can.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you want?

```
$identity=$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: I guess he wants more the kind:
$idenity = $_GET['id']; //I kept the typo

Comment: Yes that what i was looking out for , One more advice , like amazon or ebay i have a website on which data is fetch from database on search page and displayed on search page . i have multiple record displayed dynamically                                             <a href="count.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>&desc=<?php echo $row['PRO']; ?>" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">**Home**</a></li> . so is it advisable to pass value through URL is it safe

Comment: If you're using HTTPS, then it will be secure over the network, but it would still be visible to the client/browser.

Comment: @Jim Programming is about problem solving (amongst other things). If you go to amazon and execute a search what do you see? Something like this -> http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=box+of+fireworks&x=0&y=0 . So ask yourself - the biggest e-commerce site in the world is doing this.. Is it safe? What you need to ask are the 1000 other questions that relate to internet security. Do you know what SQL injection is for example (for starters)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$identity = $_GET['id'];
$desc = $_GET['desc'];
```

Make sure that you filter the contents of the $_GET array to avoid vulnerabilities. For instance, if `id` is supposed to be a number, force it:

```
$identity = (int)$_GET['id'];
```