# I need to get values from a URL and save them into a file located on the website

Tags: php, html

I don't know much PHP and so I can't figure out on how to get specific information from the URL and save it into a file located on the website.

Example of the URL:

```
http://example.com/example.php?var1=0&var2=0
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use file_get_contents or curl

Comment: befor posting the question Google it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411836/read-value-from-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 echo $_GET['var1'];
 echo $_GET['var2'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a =  $_REQUEST['var1'];
$b = $_REQUEST['var2'];
?>
```

you can use this $a and $b values fromt the url and save it anywhere in the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 

 $var1 = $_GET['var1']; 
 $var2 = $_GET['var2'];

 ?>
```

**To print this value in your page**

```
 <?php

 echo $var1; 
 echo $var2; 

 ?>
```

Comment: Here you get data from URL, but you don't answer the full question : 'save it into a file located on the website.'